# How to add days to Timestamp in Milliseconds Epoch Flutter e create a function

Tags: firebase, flutter, datetime

I need to create a function that when the thirtieth day is reached from the moment of registration the system will be block the user.
During user registration a create TimeStamp in millisecond Epoch with

```
DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
```

this will create into my database the day and the hour where the user creates his account...
Now I need to add to this TimeStamp 30 days and I need to create a function when

the TImestamp with these 30 days added

is == or >= than then registration timestamp it create an exception.

I have created with this function with FieldValue.serverTimeStamp() but of course I cant detect when this 2 fields are == but not if is greather or lesser because FieldValue doest allow ><.
Any suggestion?

Comment: `(DateTime.now() + Duration(days: 30)).millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()` will give you the `String` representation of the millisecond timestamp 30 days later.  Then all you need to do is to [parse the two `String`s as integers](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/int/parse.html) (assuming that they really need to be saved as `String`s) and perform an integer comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add two new values in your database table named 'expires' and 'status'

at the time of registration set 'expires' value:

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30));
 String expires = dateTime.toString();
```

when the user opens the app check if 'expires' is greater or smaller than today's date:

```
if(DateTime.parse(expires).compareTo(DateTime.now()) > 0) {
   //set status block
}
```